# Displaying a web page in Map Tip

Tags: qgis, qgis-3

I have searched everywhere for an answer to this but as yet have not found one so hoping somebody has done this!
I have a layer of polygons denoting the Parish areas and I have a url in a field that when clicked will open up a web page for that parish and show the carbon footprint e.g. https://impact-tool.org.uk/footprint/footprint?parishId=E04009670&footprintType=territorial&scale=absolute&showSubCategories=true
This is the url in the field.
I want this page to appear in a map tip when hovering over the relevant parish. In the map tip I've used the html notation: <iframe src="[% "comcarboncalcurl" %]" width="640" height="360" border="0"> but it is blank the map tip window shows but is blank.
I've also tried using the url string without reference to the field but again, nothing.

Anyone know the correct syntax or even if it is possible?

Comment: The page is so highly dynamic, that I can't even convert it with wkhtmltopdf which uses Qt WebKit engine as well.

Comment: Thanks Christoph. I'll not spend any more time on trying to get it to work.